# How to pass parent's state to children components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, react-native-ios

Basically, i got stuck at passing parent's component state to the child. 
I have parent component that has a dynamic content offset listener, so if I scroll down or up it updates the state with this offset value. I also got a child component, and inside that child component I've got another child component (for easier navigation through code).

That's the parent component. I checked and the state is updating whenever the scroll happens.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  contentOffset: 1
}
this.onScrollEvent = this.onScrollEvent.bind(this);
}


onScrollEvent = event => {
this.setState(
  {
    contentOffset: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y,
  }
)
}               
render() { 
   return (                                        
   <ScrollView 
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    onScroll={this.onScrollEvent.bind(this)>
       <ChildOne
          animation={this.state.contentOffset}/>
   );
 }
```

Child component

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render() { 
   return (   
   <NestedChild 
            handleClick={this.openSettingsInHeader} 
            header="What the..."
            transformAnimation={this.props.animation}/>
   );
 }
```

Child's child component

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        AnimatedTextValue: new Animated.Value(0),
        ProfileOffset: this.props.transformAnimation
    }
}

render() { 

   const animatedStyles = {
        transform: [
          { scale: 0 }]} //how to link the AnimatedTextValue to ProfileOffset? 
   return (   
   <Animated.Text style={[styles.nameStyle,animatedStyles]}>Hi!</Animated.Text>
   );
 }
```

I need to pass the state to animate the component inside that child's child component.

Comment: Have you tried passing it down to the child as a prop, and then from the child to the grandchild as a prop again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass props `transformAnimation` to the transfrom `{ scale: this.props.transformAnimation }`

Child's child component

```
render() { 
   const animatedStyles = {
        transform: [
          { scale: this.props.transformAnimation }]} // <<====  
   return (   
   <Animated.Text style={[styles.nameStyle,animatedStyles]}>Hi!</Animated.Text>
   );
 }
```

And remove from state ProfileOffset you don't need that in state. Cus you get as props from parent that value - every time when change is made.

```
 this.state = {
    AnimatedTextValue: new Animated.Value(0),
    ProfileOffset: this.props.transformAnimation   // <==== remove this
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but for the more complex things like function .interpolate (in the Animated lib), we somehow need to link this with the AnimatedTextValue: new Animated.Value(0). May be you can help me with that? Appreciate your answer.

Comment: Your welcome, can you update the post with code regarading that issue and more informations. Currently am at job, and I don't have time. But I can check later that and try to help.

Comment: Nikola, thanks, i thought that it would be better to start another question with my problem. You actually solved this one!